# Delete element from array in nested object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

How can I do this? My store is like this:

```
{
   ...,
   playlist : [
      ...,
      {
          id : 1,
          title :  "fancy-playlist-title",
          songs : [
             { id : 1 },
             { id : 2 },
             ... and so on
          ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have this reducer:

```
if(action.type === "REMOVE_FROM_PLAYLIST"){
        return {
            ...state,
            playlist : [
                ...state.playlist,
                ...state.playlist[action.index].songs.splice(0, action.indexSongs),
                ...state.playlist[action.index].songs.splice(action.indexSongs+1)
            ]
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

each playlist can have infinite songs, because playlist array contains much objects of playlist like this

```
playlist : [
   {
      id : 1,
      title : "title",
      songs : []
   },{
     id : 2,
     title : "playlist 2",
     songs : []
   },
   {... and so on}
]
```

My complete reducer is like this

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {

if(action.type === "REMOVE_FROM_PLAYLIST"){

        //action.index : current index of playlist
        //action.indexSongs : current index of song that I want to delete from current playlist

        let playlist = state.playlist[action.index].slice(0, action.index).concat(state.playlist[action.index].slice(action.index + 1));
        return {
            ...state,
            playlist : [
                ...state.playlist,
                ...playlist.slice(0, action.indexSongs),
                ...playlist.slice(action.indexSongs + 1)
            ]
        }
    }

return state;
}
```

My question is how can I delete one song of one playlist? I'm sending the index of current playlist and the index of the song of current playlist.

Comment: just for future - consider using immutable.js - you can more easily manipulate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`splice` *mutates* the array state, which you should not be doing.

What you want is a combination of  ***`slice`*** and `concat`:

```
playlist.slice(0, indexOfSong)  // copy a portion of the array
                                // from the start to the indexOfSong

        .concat(                // concatenate it with:

          playlist.slice(indexOfSong + 1)
                                // copy of a portion of the array from
                                // the index just after indexOfSong
                                // to the end of the playlist
        );
```

The above can be written using ES6 Spread syntax as follows:

```
[
  ...playlist.slice(0, indexOfSong)
  ...playlist.slice(indexOfSong + 1));
]
```

> EDIT, considering your recent question update, your reducer should look like
>   this:
>
> ```
> export default function(state = {}, action) {
>
> if(action.type === "REMOVE_FROM_PLAYLIST"){
>   return {
>             ...state,
>             playlist : [
>                 ...state.playlist,
>                 ...playlist[action.index].songs.slice(0, action.indexSongs),
>                 ...playlist[action.index].songs.slice(action.indexSongs + 1)
>             ]
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: in this case  "concat(list.slice(indexOfSong + 1);", what means list? this.state.playlist[action.index]?, thanks for helping too fast

Comment: Typo :)  Corrected it now

Comment: Thought I'd expand upon this a bit, so added some comments, hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but following your code example, i'm getting an error that says "undefined is not a function state.playlist[action.index].slice(0,action.indexOfSong)"

Comment: Are you sure `state[action.index]` resolves to an array?  Could you post up your complete reducer?  Also check out my alternative syntax using the ES6 spread syntax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128872/discussion-between-dante-cervantes-and-pineda).

Answer (score 1):

If you use lodash, you could use _.merge

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#merge

```
if(action.type === "REMOVE_FROM_PLAYLIST"){
    let newPlaylistWihoutDeletedItem = state.playlist.splice(action.index, 1);

    return _.merge({}, state, {
      playlist: newPlaylistWihoutDeletedItem
    });
}
```

Comment: mutation is not allowed in redux `reducers`